# Checking TD for a specific value

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have half of this working the way I want it to work. However, I am having a issue that I can not find a solution to.

I am trying to find a value of 9999 in one of the my TD's. 9999 in this case means that that record **Needs** to be updated since 9999 is used to express a large number with no meaning to our staff.

The issue though is that though if there is no 9999 in my TD the Jquery action is still taking place. Please take a look at the screen shots :

In this situation it works just fine. I want the new text boxes to appear so that we can update the students information and what not.
[image]

Now in this situation this an actual "valid" student with proper information **without a 9999** in the TD and it still shows the update text boxes. I do not want this to happen.
[image]

This is my Jquery :

```
if ($("#datatables td:contains(9999)")) {
    $(".upd").prop('checked', true);
    $(".upd").css("display", "none");
}
```

Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is always true because the selector is returning a jQuery object.  You want to check its length property.

```
if ($("#datatables td:contains(9999)").length !== 0) {
```

This will then make sure that you actually have elements in the selector.

Comment: This works, but I do not understand what you mean by "returning a jQuery object" If I didn't ask this question on SO where could I read on about this issue? I'm very new to Jquery

Comment: @RixhersAjazi `$()` constructs a jQuery object, and will always return true, because it is `a jQuery object`. That being said, `.length` will tell you if the selector being returned in the jQuery object exists in the DOM, which is a separate check all together.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

The return of the function is an object created by jQuery